# Why does opening/writing a large number of files fail in C?

Tags: c, printf

I want to write in 1000000 text files, opened by a C program. In a loop, I call a function that it writes in text files. Text files were created previously. The program can only open 508 text files and write in them. Why?

The code is:

```
int main()
{
    char* s[1000000];

    for(i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        /* Initialize s[i] */
        export( s[i] );
    }
}

static int export( char* filename )
{
    FILE* file;
    int i, j, d;

    file = fopen( filename, "w+" );

    if( ! ( file ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Warning: error opening %s, %s, line %d in export",
        filename, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
        return 1;
    }
    d = feat[0].d;

    fprintf( file, "%d %d\n", n, d );

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        fprintf( file, "%f %f %f %f", feat[i].y, feat[i].x,
        feat[i].scl, feat[i].ori );

        for( j = 0; j < d; j++ )
        {
            /* write 20 descriptor values per line */
            if( j % 20 == 0 )
            fprintf( file, "\n" );
            fprintf( file, " %d", (int)(feat[i].des[j]) );
        }
        fprintf( file, "\n" );
    }

    if( fclose(file) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Warning: file close error, %s, line %d\n",
        __FILE__, __LINE__ );
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code work perfectly for 508 first text files and then I get exception error that can not open next file.

Comment: Do you get an error ?

Comment: Please reindent your code

Comment: Use `perror` to obtain the cause of a failure.

Comment: `char* s[1000000];`, did u allocate memory? code shows only passing it  to function. where values are assigned?

Comment: No, I do not get any error. I just want to write in 1000000 text files. export function open one file and write in it, then close it.

Comment: @Jens No. `s` is an array of `char *`.

Comment: `/* Initialize s[i]*/` **how** do you do this?

Comment: what OS are you using? And are there already a large amount of file in the folder you're writing. Some file systems have a limit in the number of files in a folder, for example [exFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) allows up to 2,796,202 per directory

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using a bunch of uninitialized character pointers as filenames; it's not very surprising that one of them is interpreted as a filename that's invalid. This is undefined behavior, unless you actually initialize `s` to something.

It seems extremely strange to pre-allocate the array of filenames; you only ever need one at a time so why waste a huge amount of memory doing that?

You should probably do something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
{
  char filename[64];
  sprintf(filename, "file-%d", i);
  export(filename);
}
```

This will generate filenames like `file-0`, `file-1` and so on.

Comment: I initialized the s[i], but did not put it here.

Comment: How did you initialize the s[i] ??

Comment: By creating address of files. This code work perfectly for 508 first files, then I got an exception error that can not open the next text file.

Comment: @user2758590 Don't talk about it, **show us the code**.

Comment: @user2758590: and please show what *exactly* is displayed when the exception occurs. And tell us on platform (Linux, Windows, Macintosh, ...) you are using.

Comment: @unwind why `filename[64];`? I mean, the largest filename this code produces is `file-999999` of length 11, plus the '\0', 12 characters max. I think 64 bytes is too much, even for a computer with 8GB of ram.

Comment: Because I didn't know what filename pattern I was going to use, plus the original code already has an array of 1,000,000 filenames, plus for general (PC) code I really don't care.

Comment: Now,my platform is windows. But this problem exists in linux too.

Comment: @user2758590 That comment is on the wrong answer. You are very frustrating since you seemingly refuse to provide additional detail. I've voted for closing this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you get an error after processing 508 files, I suspect you run into the implementation limit of the number of simultaneously opened files. If that is the case, you should `fclose(fp)` each file when done writing. (508 is 511 minus 3 for stdout, stdin, stderr).

Note that the C Standard only guarantees that you can open `FOPEN_MAX` (stdio.h) files at the same time, which might be as low as 8.

Or maybe you bump into some other limit like disk quota exceeded or no space left on device? What is the particular error? Add a call to `perror()` when an fopen, fprintf or fclose fails.

Are we seeing your export() function **exactly** as you use it? Or did you strip it down to show the logic? If the latter, look for early `return` statements other than those after the fopen/fclose. An early return might cause what we call a **resource leak** (analogous to memory leak, but the resource leaking here is file descriptors/streams).

Comment: How should close files? Does not export function close each file.

Comment: Then we have identified your problem. I see your export() which uses fclose, but since this is only part of the whole program, I can only speculate. Add an open file counter initialized with zero, increment it for each successful fopen, decrement it for each successful fclose and print it in various places. Maybe there really are more fopen() than fclose() calls.